# Change background image dynamicly in PDFmake

Tags: javascript, css, image, pdfmake

From the documentation i see this:

```
var docDefinition = {
 background: function(currentPage) {
return 'simple text on page ' + currentPage
},
content: (...)
};
```

Which nicely gives dynamic changing background text..

I currently use the following for the background:

```
    background: [{
    image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRX...='
    ,fit: [595, 842]
    }];
```

But since it is a multi-page document, and i would like to change the images on page 2,3,4,, etc..

In my mind i should do something like:

```
var defined_image_arrray =  ['image1','image2','image3'];

var docDefinition = {
 background: function(currentPage) {
image: defined_image_array[currentPage];
},
content: (...)
};
```

But it does not work..

'''''
Added on 14-11-2017
'''''

The following prints the data source on the page:

```
var defined_image_arrray =  ['image1','image2','image3'];

var docDefinition = {
background:     
function(currentPage, pageCount, pageSize) { return "" + defined_image_arrray[currentPage].toString() + "" }
};
```

'''''

The following shows the background image correct:

```
var defined_image_arrray =  ['image1','image2','image3'];

background:     
[{  
image: defined_image_arrray[0]  
,
fit: [595, 842]
}]
```

'''''

The following creates this error message:

"invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)"

```
var defined_image_arrray =  ['image1','image2','image3'];

background:     
[{
image: function(currentPage, pageCount, pageSize) { return "" + defined_image_arrray[currentPage].toString() + "" }
,
fit: [595, 842]
}]
```

I don't understand why it is like this.. Can anyone give a suggestion on how i pass the pagenumber to the image array ?

Comment: Can be done by using background as a function, as per examples here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1167 & here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/861